# How can you accurately round a floating point number in javascript?

Tags: javascript, math, floating-point, decimal, rounding

> I have looked in many places for an answer for this including but not
>   limited to https://stackoverflow.com, and I am not here
>   attempting to duplicate a question. I'm here to get a definitive
>   answer as to how to best alleviate this problem. I would appreciate
>   any help I can get on this as I'm sure many others will as well. Thank
>   you very much.

**0.9999*0.9999 != 0.9998000100000001**

I am writing a Google Chrome extension calculator. Preferably one that gives the right answer, but weird answers like that I keep getting. Really need to figure this one out.

I have instituted **Math.js** for its robust Math capabilities. For rounding, I have used **math.round()**, two functions I will post below, and as a last ditch effort before posting a question on here, **Big.js** for rounding and additional help with big numbers later on.

With every rounding function I have found so far on the internet, the closest answer to correct that I have been able to achieve is **0.99980001** which is not the correct answer. The correct answer is **0.9998**.

I have looked at **toPrecision()** and **toFixed()** but I have to somehow know which one and how many decimals places are needed for any random result to any random equation which just isn't realistically possible unless the user specifies a particular number of decimal places, but even then they would still want the correct answer.

I thought about writing an artificially intelligent heuristic algorithm to discern the appropriate number of significant digits in any decimal string, but this solution is both time consuming and seems a bit of overkill as there has to be a solution to this already implemented somewhere or somehow.

The code used to do the math and process the answer:

```
//math_eval[0] = gaussRound(Round(math.eval(math_str), 15), 15);
//math_eval[0] = math.format(math.eval(math_str), {precision: 14});
//math_eval[0] = Big(math.eval(math_str));
//math_eval[0] = math_eval[0].round(math_eval[0]);
//bg = new Big(math.eval(math_str));
//math_eval[0] = Round(bg.round(14), 14);
math_eval[0] = math.eval(math_str);
```

The two rounding functions that you see being called other than built in or **Big.js**:

```
// http://thenewcode.com/895/JavaScript-Rounding-Recipes
//
// Discovered significant digit errors and this function
// seems to alleviate them.
function gaussRound(num, decimalPlaces) 
{
    var d = decimalPlaces || 0,
    m = Math.pow(10, d),
    n = +(d ? num * m : num).toFixed(15),
    i = Math.floor(n), f = n - i,
    e = 1e-8,
    r = (f > 0.5 - e && f < 0.5 + e) ? ((i % 2 == 0) ? i : i + 1) : Math.round(n);
    return d ? r / m : r;
}

// a second rounding function since even the one above still fails
function Round(Number, DecimalPlaces) 
{
    return Math.round(parseFloat(Number) * Math.pow(10, DecimalPlaces)) / Math.pow(10, DecimalPlaces);
}
```

Comment: What is 0.9998 the correct answer to? It's not the answer to multiplying 0.9999 by 0.9999, which is 0.99980001. You can reproduce by multiplying 9999 by 9999 and mentally adjusting the decimal point

Comment: To be honest I was using a TI emulator to check the math. With your comment, it makes me want to do some more research. I was wrong once before. Thx for the clarification.

Comment: You are welcome and I tried to take off the down vote but was refused.  Please consider deleting the question if it is based on a false premise.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it uses a mistaken premise.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, I discovered that indeed the TI-89 I was using to check my math has flawed rounding. This is, by far, the last thing I'd expect from a world class calculator.

I'm fairly certain that many people knowing not to trust the answer they get from a TI calculator at face value is potentially damaging to ones reputation is valuable in of itself.

This matter is resolved.